# Checking Valid Membership

Tags: javascript, php, api

I just can't get my head around this, I'm probably just missing it but let me know if you can help.

Issue: It's stating that the User is a member, even though they are not.

For example if the user is not in the User Auth table, it should display "Not a Member" where if the user is in the table it should display "Member"

**Issue**

[image]

**Table Structure :** 
user_auth table : 
[image]

This is the Js that is executed on all pages

```
function GetUserinfo(token)
{
    var info = { Token: token };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Api/CurrentUser",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $(".account .user").html(data.Username);
            if(data.Member == 0)
            {
                $(".account .status").html("<p style=\"color:red;\">Not a member</p>");
            } else {
                $(".account .status").html("<p style=\"color:green;\">Member</p>");
            }
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Rest API
 ` elseif($parameter == "CurrentUser") {
            $params = $this->dataStream();

```
        $user = new User(null, $params['Token']);

        echo '{ "Username":"' . htmlspecialchars($user->fetch("username")) . '", "Member": ' . $user->hasMembership() . ' }';
        http_response_code(200);
    }
}`
```

Here is the hasMembership function

```
 public function hasMembership()
{
    $uid = $this->fetch("uid");
    $this->queryObj->Execute("SELECT * FROM user_auth WHERE uid=:uid ", "prepare", array($uid), 0);

    return ($this->queryObj->rows >= 1);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just a side comment on your table. Don't give up an opportunity to be more verbose in your column names. I can only assume you were asking since you have the 'How would I do (it)' Column.

Comment: The HWID column stands for Hardware identification.

Comment: try to dump the value of data.Member, console.log(data.Member); It's not 0, but what is it?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l7yegd

Comment: Why posting an image tho? your cosole.log(data.Member) equals to 1

Comment: Thought it would be easier, and yes it equals to 1

Comment: Are you using PDO (can't seems to remember any Execute method with that kind of input parameters) or any other abstraction layers?

Comment: Yes, I am using PDO, and no other than where the function GetUserinfo is being called on the dashboard.js

Comment: I think you need to read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". For fast answers, we need to be able to copy and paste the code into our own environment, you're missing how your User instance is being created via the token. Have you tried to `console.log(data.Username)` to ensure it is acquiring the correct user? We can't see any logs or data.

Comment: The problem is to do with the hasMembership function, if one of yous would be able to contact me on discord it would be much more help. IAMSINATRA#4941